# Unity Add single axis rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good day, having a problem with adding a single axis to a rotation. 
I have an external method that sets rotation in 2d on a plane, bound to a player character.
But it can not use Y-axis so weapon rotation is limited to the x-z plane.
The exposed method has a queterion entry for that rotation, and I'm struggling to add a vertical part to it.

```
protected virtual void RotateWeapon(Quaternion newRotation)
    {
        if (GameManager.Instance.Paused)
        {
            return;
        }

        RaycastHit hit;
        Physics.Raycast(_reticlePosition, Vector3.down * 1000, out hit);
        Debug.DrawLine(_reticlePosition, hit.point, Color.red);
        //Hit.point.z is a vertical part i need to add to newRotation

        // if the rotation speed is == 0, we have instant rotation
        if (WeaponRotationSpeed == 0)
        {
            transform.rotation = newRotation;
        }
        // otherwise we lerp the rotation
        else
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, WeaponRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add rotations by multiplying the two `Quaternions` with the [`*` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html) like

```
newRotation *= additionalRotation;
```

Then in order to generate the `additionalRotation` you can use [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) and pass in a `Vector3` representing the rotation split into it's Euler angle components for each axis.

I didn't completely understand your usecase but if you want to rotate e.g. only around the Z axis you would do

```
newRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * angle);
```

---

Or if you rather wanted to take the given `Quaternion` but limit it to only rotate on a certain axis like Z you could use

```
newRotation =  Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.Scale(Vector3.forward, newRotation.euerAngles));
```

where you can replace the `Vector3.forward` with any other vector indicating which axis angles should be used like e.g. `new Vector3(1,0,1)` for keeping the X and Z rotation but eliminate the Y rotation (see [`Vector3.Scale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Scale.html))